# Accessing context-param values from within a RESTEasy provider

Tags: java, configuration, jax-rs, resteasy

I have created a `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` that needs to
read a configuration value. Ideally I'd like this to be held in the
`web.xml` as a `context-param`. Is there any way that a RESTEasy provider
can access context params? Is there any type that I can inject using
`@Context` that will allow me to get `context-param` values? I haven't
been able to find one.

Alternatively, is there a better way to provide configuration values
to a provider? I'd like to avoid having to use a system property.

Comment: Why not add your own application configuration file and define all your settings in that?

Comment: I'd like the avoid a propagation of bespoke properties files. JEE already defines a configuration file for web applications, it would be nice to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question, one solution is to use Spring.

When RESTEasy beans are created via the the Spring context, one can easily provide configuration values in the application-context.xml. It's even possible to use context-param values from the web.xml using the [ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html).